# It´s possible to alter specific table for each database on mysql sgbd?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to generate a query to alter one table of each database of my SGDB. I can get each database name that I want to alter, but then, I don't know how to continue.

This is the query to select each database name:

```
 SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `database`
 FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
 WHERE  SCHEMA_NAME like 'customer_db_%'
 ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME
```

Before the % is the number of the database. I´m trying to add one column on one table of each database.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `database`
 FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
 WHERE  SCHEMA_NAME like '%customer_db_%'
 ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME
```

Comment: Hi SAVe, thanks for your response. Maybe I´m not clear or I can´t undestand you. I´m trying to get something like this (ATENTION, THIS DON´T WORK):

```ALTER TABLE concat((SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `database` FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE  SCHEMA_NAME like '%customer_db_%' ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME),'.school') ADD schoolNum CHAR(10) NOT NULL AFTER sectionNum```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a stored procedure to implement this as you can't use variable values as table names. Something like this should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_db_tables (IN db_pattern VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  DECLARE db, tbl VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE db_table CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.`TABLES`;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
  OPEN db_table;
db_loop: LOOP
    FETCH db_table INTO db, tbl;
    IF done = 1 THEN
      LEAVE db_loop;
    END IF;
    IF db LIKE db_pattern THEN
      SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', db, '.', tbl, ' ADD schoolNum CHAR(10) NOT NULL AFTER sectionNum');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
  END LOOP db_loop;
END;
```

You would then execute it using

```
CALL update_db_tables('customer_db_%');
```

I would recommend testing the procedure before executing it by replacing:

```
EXECUTE stmt;
```

with

```
SELECT @sql;
```

to make sure the queries are what you expect them to be. Also it would be advisable to back up your database before making such a big change as this.

Comment: @Antonio Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?